# How to find XML Elements by prefixed attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have following XML:

```
<r xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">
    <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
        <r uid="{B19D0460-69C9-4FEC-A882-41FFA77B582F}" p:before="r[@uid='{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}']" s:ds="/Polecane" s:id="{C3AC52FB-8F51-4B44-A3EE-55F4C2EAF83F}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />

        <r uid="{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}" p:before="r[@uid='{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}']" s:ds="/HITY" s:id="{7A80D822-8D6A-40C4-92D4-2FA22C596339}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />

        <r uid="{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}" p:before="r[@uid='{B6036949-B723-42CE-9271-64DF299450DC}']" s:ds="/VOD" s:id="{557800E7-953B-4830-8691-3FFB964712A8}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    </d>
</r>
```

I store it in String variable. Can I find node with

```
s:ds="/Polecane"
```

then get its "uid" and set it in "p:before" in HITY node?

Comment: You should probably have shown us what you tried. That would have got you fewer downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XDocument:

```
string xml = @"<r xmlns:p=""p"" xmlns:s=""s"" p:p=""1"">
    <d id=""{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}"">
        <r uid=""{B19D0460-69C9-4FEC-A882-41FFA77B582F}"" p:before=""r[@uid='{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}']"" s:ds=""/Polecane"" s:id=""{C3AC52FB-8F51-4B44-A3EE-55F4C2EAF83F}"" s:par="""" s:ph=""moviesplaceholder"" />

        <r uid=""{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}"" p:before=""r[@uid='{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}']"" s:ds=""/HITY"" s:id=""{7A80D822-8D6A-40C4-92D4-2FA22C596339}"" s:par="""" s:ph=""moviesplaceholder"" />

        <r uid=""{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}"" p:before=""r[@uid='{B6036949-B723-42CE-9271-64DF299450DC}']"" s:ds=""/VOD"" s:id=""{557800E7-953B-4830-8691-3FFB964712A8}"" s:par="""" s:ph=""moviesplaceholder"" />
    </d>
</r>";

XNamespace nsS = "s";
XNamespace nsP = "p";

XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XElement elPolecane = xd.Descendants("r").Where(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ds") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ds").Value == "/Polecane").FirstOrDefault();
if (elPolecane != null)
{
    string uid = elPolecane.Attribute("uid").Value;
    XElement elHITY = xd.Descendants("r").Where(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ds") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ds").Value == "HITY").FirstOrDefault();
    if (elHITY != null)
    {
        elHITY.Attribute(nsP + "before").SetValue("r[@uid='" + uid + "']");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xd.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
  //variable which holds xml data
  string xml = "<r>......</r>";
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  //XML in XmlDocument
  doc.LoadXml(xml);
  XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//d/r");
  string uid = "";
  //Parse all r nodes
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    if (node.Attributes["s:ds"].InnerText == "/Polecane")
    {
      uid = node.Attributes["uid"].InnerText;
    }
  }
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    if (node.Attributes["s:ds"].InnerText == "/HITY")
    {
      //Update attribute
      node.Attributes["p:before"].InnerText = uid;
    }
  }
  doc.Save(@"C:\tmp\xmldocument.xml");
```

Comment: You saw `node.Attributes["s:ds"].InnerText` return the correct value? I would be very surprised, since that can't work for elements, and since namespace prefixes aren't meant to be significant.

Comment: Yes it's correct if i loop through, but XPath does not work with this "s:ds".
 Thats why i don't use SelectSingleNode.

Comment: Well, it may (just possibly) not crash, but it's not "correct". The namespace prefix is permitted to change as long as the actual namespace stays the same. Your code will break as soon as the prefix changes.